# OS X options key mapping

Tags: macos, keyboard, mapping

Many years ago I switched to OS X but I wanted to keep using my old decent IBM keyboard. So I wrote a very tiny script to map the options key to the caps lock.

Now I want to start using an Apple keyboard but because of that script my left options key doesn't function.

Even if I create a new user on my Mac I have the same problem.

- Where can I find the script I wrote? I can't remember if it was AppleScript or shell script. It is not in /System/Library/StartupItems.
- Is it possible to reset the keyboard layout programmatically?

Comment: What version os OS X you use please ?

Comment: Now I have El Capitan but I can't remember which version I had when I installed the script.

Comment: Another possibility is to map the right options key to the left options key because that's the only key that doesn't function